# How to display flask data on URL path

Tags: python, flask

hi I created a simple website to calculate the square of the number. below is the code

calculate.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">
    <title>Flask </title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        square
    </header>
    <div class="congrat">
        {{ result }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

homepage.html

```
<form method="post" action="/square">
    <div class="calculate">
        <b>Square</b><br/>Num
        <input type="text" name="number"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="calculate">
    </div>
</form>
```

python

```
@app.route("/square", methods=['POST'])
def square():
    number = request.form["number"]
    return render_template("calculate.html", result = int(number) ** 2)
```

now I want to display input number in URL path. e.g. http://127.0.0.1:3000/square/10

so I've tried this

```
<form method="post" action="/square/<number>">
    <div class="calculate">
        <b>Square</b><br/>Num
        <input type="text" name="number"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="calculate">
    </div>
</form>

@app.route("/square/<number>", methods=['POST'])
def square(number):
    number = request.form["number"]
    return render_template("calculate.html", result = int(number) ** 2)
```

but it didn't work. What could I do?

Comment: In your python code you are rendering the `result` variable, but it does not appear anywhere in your html.

Comment: @TDG sorry I forgot to put calculate.html in. my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get variables directly parsed from Flask URL

```py
@app.route("/square/<number>", methods=['POST'])
def square(number):
    return render_template("calculate.html", result = int(number) ** 2)
```

Edit:

```html
<form id="your_form" method="post" onsubmit="yourFunction()">
    <input type="text" name="keywords">
    <input type="text" name="number"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="calculate">
</form>
 <script>
function yourFunction(){
    var action_src = "/square/" + document.getElementsByName("number")[0].value;
    var your_form = document.getElementById('your_form');
    your_form.action = action_src ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: yeah I've tried this one. But when I key in the value, like 127.0.0.1:3000/square/10 it shows Not Found. So I added 'GET' into method. I get the answer but id didn't connect with my html.

Comment: How about `number = request.view_args['number']`, it should work. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Request.view_args. >  What does `I get the answer but id didn't connect with my html`  mean?

Comment: well I created a homepage and an input area. I want to turn to the result page when I key in the number. but I don't know how to connect it. the original code is `<form method="post" action="/square"` and I tried `'action="/square/<number>"` but it didn't work

Comment: I have edited the answer, perhaps the javascript part is what you want.

Comment: thx for the answer. I've tried your answer and it successfully turn to the result page but still not connect with the html part. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: oh it says GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/square/homepage.css net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: The `number` variable must be a valid integer, because you are doing the math calculation `int(number) ** 2`. `homepage.css` is not a valid integer, int("homepage.css") will certainly return an error. What does `connect to the html` mean?